# Solving equation with functions inside the function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I've been given the problem: 
For h(x) defined below, find h′(2),  given that:
 f(2)=−3, g(2)=3 , f′(2)=−1 and g′(2)=7.

h(x) = f(x)g(x)

I was thinking 
h'(x) = (-1)(7)
      = -7

Is this right? If not, could somebody give me a step by step guide to solving this? Thanks guys.

Comment: No, it’s not right. HINT: Use the product rule.

Comment: Got it! Thanks man!!

Comment: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(fg) = f\dfrac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dx} + g \dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$$